# How to get point coordinates of a modified drawingManager shape? GoogleMaps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this DrawingManager Object:

```
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      markerOptions: {
        draggable: true
      },
      polylineOptions: {
        editable: true
      },
      polygonOptions: polyOptions,
      map: map
    });
```

And when a Polygon is completed I get their coords with:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
        var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
        console.log(coordinates);
      });
```

But if I change the polygon using DrawingManager obviously the shape will change, maybe adding more Points..
Then How can I get all Points with their coords after modify it and for example click a button to finish the edition?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, obviously I need implement a button for finish the shape edition, when I will click it I should get the data...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok having the answer on my second code:

```
var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
```

Finally I got the last array with coordinates calling this code by adding a listener to call a function that get the array:

JS

```
function getCoordinates() {
    console.log(polygon.getPath().getArray());
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('CoordsButton'), 'click', getCoordinates);
```

HTML

```
<button id="CoordsButton">Coordinates</button>
```

Then when the button is clicked now I get the coords...

Thanks anyway

Comment: When I try this right now, the array of the real coordinates array would be unter `coordinates[0].j`.

Answer (score 1):

Heres our solution for passing the coordinates of a polygon using a for loop using an event listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(testMap, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    var coordinates = (polygon.getPath());
    console.log(coordinates);

for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.getLength(); i++) 
 {
   const xy = coordinates.getAt(i);
   var contentString = console.log(JSON.stringify({point: xy +[i+1]}))
 }
```