# How do I capture point locations of Polygon with Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps API Drawing Manager, I want to collect the location of each point in the polygon that is drawn by a user.

I know there is a `getPath()` function, but I'm not sure where I use it.

This is all the code I have so far:

```
var map; var drawingManager;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.13536, -100.762952),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        drawingControl: false,
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: "#000000",
            fillOpacity: .6,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            strokeColor: "#666666",
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1
        }
    });

    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

So from this code, how can I use the `getPath()` function to show the coordinates that make up the Polygon that is drawn?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get point coordinates of a modified drawingManager shape? GoogleMaps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407451/how-to-get-point-coordinates-of-a-modified-drawingmanager-shape-googlemaps-api)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use it inside the polygoncomplete-callback.

example:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    var arr=[];
    polygon.getPath().forEach(function(latLng){arr.push(latLng.toString());})
    alert(arr.join(',\n'));
});
```

it iterates over the path(using the forEach-method of a google.maps.MVCArray) and populates another array with the string-representations of the LatLng's

Comment: the polygon-argument is a [google.maps.Polygon-instance](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#Polygon) - the argument(representing the polygon that has been completed) will be passed automatically by the API(see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing#drawing_events )